# Trapped Radiation inside a Faraday Cage

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Say you have a Faraday cage mesh with holes small enough to reflect the radio waves. What happens to radiation when it is emitted from inside the Faraday cage?

Does it keep reflecting off of the inside of the cage forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Unless the cage is a perfect conductor (which it is impossible in real life to make or find), a portion of the energy of the waves will get absorbed by the walls of the cage on each reflection, eventually causing the wave to attenuate or "die out". Given the incredible speed of light, these reflections happen close to a billion times each second in a cage around $1\, \mathrm{m}^3$ in volume, so the attenuation happens really quickly.

The absorbed radiation (electromagnetic energy) gets transformed into another form of energy, usually heat. The walls of the conductor heat up slightly as a result.

Typically, the radiation penetrates a characteristic distance called the "[skin depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)" inside the material of the conductor, before falling to around $1/3$ of its initial strength. For example, copper has a skin depth of around $8.5 \, \mathrm{mm}$ for a radiation of frequency $60\, \mathrm{Hz}$. The conductor will get heated up *as the wave is attenuating*; it is a continuous process.

Comment: What happens to the radiation absorbed by the inside walls of the cage?

Comment: @Masu It is transformed to another form of energy, usually heat. The walls of the cage heat up and expand ever so slightly.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would the absorbed radiation travel through the walls of the cage for any reason?  Or would it just immediately be dissipated into heat?

Comment: @Masu I've added my comments to my answer :)

Comment: @Masu No problem.

Comment: hi Yejus, I was hoping you could clear up this doubt for me, on this page: https://www.eiwellspring.org/emc/ShieldSimpleRoom.htm.  If you search for the keyword "trapped"  it talks about how if you use aluminum foil to shield a room, and you use a cell phone or cordless phone, that the radiation emitted will be trapped from inside that room.  And you would be more exposed to radiation building up inside the room than if you did not shield the room at all.  It would do more harm than good.  Why would it be trapped in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no. It will be trapped in the cage only if it's very controlled.